# How to stretch ImageButton without the image getting blurred?

Tags: android, android-layout

I create a new `ImageButton` via the "Resource Chooser" and I end up with this code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mybutton" />
```

Now, I want to make that button way bigger, so I do the following changes:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aries" />
```

I also change the `android:src="@drawable/mybutton"` to `android:background="@drawable/mybutton"` to get rid of the grey button around my image and stretch the image instead.

**Problem:**

My problem is that when stretching out the image it still uses the file from the `drawable-mdpi` (as it should), so I end up with a stretched low resolution image. If I change the image from the `drawable-mdpi` folder with a high resolution one it looks great, but I am pretty sure that this is not the best solution out there as I would have to put an image with bigger resolution in each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like what you need is a [Nine-Patch Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch).

> A NinePatch is a PNG image in which you can define stretchable regions that Android scales when content within the View exceeds the normal image bounds. [...] when the View grows to accomodate the content, the Nine-Patch image is also scaled to match the size of the View.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting the background to **`null`**:

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: This makes the grey background transparent. I need to stretch the image over it.

Comment: Then @Nicklas is right, You have to use [Nine Patch](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)